# Cookie Problem with ASP.NET / ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

new Version of Firefox and IE8 seem to use one windows process. We have a multi-tenancy web application which gets testet by our support team. they have different cases open at the same time which produce side-effects as the session is the same for the instance.

is there a possibility to solve this problem by code? i think sessionstate cookieless=true is no option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you should modify your application code for this. Modify the way it is tested because in the real world that's how the application will be used.

So for IE8 you could use the [-nomerge command line option](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/07/22/run-separate-isolated-ie8-window-frame-session-with-nomerge-switch-for-multiple-logins/) when launching `iexplore.exe`. Another possibility is play with the [TabProcGrowth](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/04/07/seven-things-you-should-known-about-ie-8/) setting in the registry.